# Sort an array with DOM tags and attributes by left and top values

Tags: javascript

I have got an array with DOM tags (div -> children img -> div closed). Those tags has attributes (left and top values). I added em as nodeLists so i can access elements offsetLeft and offsetTop to determine those values but i cant figurate out how to rearange those tags in the array ascending by left or top values.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div style="left:40px;top:10px;position:absolute">
        <img src="assets/images/text1.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="left:200px;top:88px;position:absolute">
        <img src="assets/images/text2.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="left:85px;top:166px;position:absolute">
        <img src="assets/images/text3.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var unsortedElements = [];
        var sortedElements = [];

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > div");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            if (element != null) {
                unsortedElements.push(element);

                var x = element.offsetLeft;
                var y = element.offsetTop;
                customSort(unsortedElements[i]);
            }
        }

function customSort(element){
var left = element.offsetLeft;

sortedElements.push(left);
console.log(sortedElements); -> will return the left values (40,85,200) BUT i need this array sorted with div tags (like [<div style="left: 40px;">img child</div>, <div style="left: 85px;">img child</div>, <div style="left: 200px;">img child</div>])

}
```

**Note**

Pure Javascript please!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **high order function** to create custom filter, in order to filter DOM element.

You can do the following :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

//Create our function generator
function sortBy(prop){
  return function(a, b){
    var filter_a = parseInt( a.style[prop] );
    var filter_b = parseInt( b.style[prop] );
    return filter_a < filter_b
    ? -1
    : (filter_a > filter_b ? 1 : 0);
  }
}

function sortDom(filter){
  //Transform our nodeList into array and apply sort function
  return [].map.call(elements, function(elm){
    return elm;
  }).sort(sortBy(filter))
}

//Sort by left style property
var byLeft = sortDom('left');
//Sort by top style property
var byTop = sortDom('top');
```

Comment: Excelent answer @Paul Boutes. Thank you!

Comment: I like the higher order function idea. But wouldn't the comparison of the raw style attributes result in "2px" being considered greater than "100px", as they're both strings?

Comment: We have to remove the `px` from `2px`, otherwise we will get a `NaN` as result. I just find that is simpler to use the `parseInt()` function. But obviously, you can perform comparison between string ex : "100" - "2" = 98

Answer (score 3):

With ES6, you get a new bunch of functions to have the job done more elegantly.
For the purpose of that update, i'm just going to sort for the left property.
I guess the replacement of a comparator function is straightforward from now on.

**HTML**

```
<caption>Sorting by left offset</caption>
<div id="container" style="position:relative">
    <div class="candidate" style="left:200px;top:88px;position:absolute">
        <span>3 was 1 before sorting</span>
    </div>
    <div class="candidate" style="left:40px;top:10px;position:absolute">
        <span>1 was 2 before sorting</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="candidate" style="left:85px;top:166px;position:absolute">
        <span>2 was 3 before sorting</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Pure JavaScript / EcmaScript 2015**

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.candidate")).sort(function(a, b){
    let aLeft = a.style.left.replace("px","");
    let bLeft = b.style.left.replace("px","");
    return aLeft-bLeft;
}).forEach(function(el){
    document.querySelectorAll("#container")[0].appendChild(el);
});
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/a4e41pmr/

I used `appendChild` as a trick to move the nodes once sorted.

Comment: That solution is close to @icke 's one. But the language benefits from the `Array.from()` static and native method, that is able to convert a _NodeList_ to an _Array_ on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sort` function of javascript arrays. Unfortunately that doesn't work on nodelists (which you get from calling `querySelectorAll`), so you have to do some converting:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body > div");
var divs=[];
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    divs.push(elements[i]);
}
```

This puts all your elements into an array. Now for the sorting:

```
divs.sort(function(a,b){
    var aLeft = a.style.left.replace("px","");
    var bLeft = b.style.left.replace("px","");
    return aLeft-bLeft;
});
```

This sorts by the `left` style attribute, provided that they're all in the form `123px`.

In practice I would probably do it as @Paul Boutes suggested as it's more generic, but I thought that this way might be easier to understand.